# APEX error: 400 Bad Request - Request Header Or Cookie Too Large (nginx)

Tags: oracle-apex

When I am changing APEX interactive report regions (add items to submit, rename report column etc) and save changes, I get following error: **400 Bad Request** - *Request Header Or Cookie Too Large*.

Then whole application is blocked and I have to remove cookies or restart the browser and log in again to be able to work.

Do you know what is the cause of this error and how to fix that?
APEX 23.1.5

Comment: I'm seeing this behaviour too. I think that after a while, as a developer a cookie fills up and this error is thrown. Not sure anything can be done about it.